# Dynamic Section in Form

Tags: javascript

I am creating a form and I have a field set for client information and the ability to add another field set for another client if needed.

As of now the additional field sets' field id adds by 1 which is good, but I would like for each of the fields in the field set to add by 1 as well.

```
var _counter = 0;
function Add() {
_counter++;
var oClone = document.getElementById("client1").cloneNode(true);
oClone.id += (_counter + "");
document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(oClone);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a page that clones and increments the fieldset as well as any children elements within the set.  It's assuming that both fieldset and children inputs have a numeric suffix.  i.e. fieldset1 and textfield2, etc.

Cheers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


  <script type='text/javascript'>
    // store a reference to the last clone so I can increment off that.
    window.lastClone = null;

    function incrementId(id) {
      // regexp is looking for text with a number suffix.  adjust accordingly.
      var numberSuffixRegExp = /(.*?)(\d*)$/;
      var regExpMatch = numberSuffixRegExp.exec(id);
      // assuming a match will be made here, and position 1 and 2 are populated.
      var prefix = regExpMatch[1];
      var counter = parseInt(regExpMatch[2]);
      counter++;
      return prefix + counter;
    }

    function cloneFieldSet() {

      if (!window.lastClone) {
        window.lastClone = 'fieldset1';
      }

      var newFieldSet = document.getElementById(lastClone).cloneNode(true);

      newFieldSet.id = incrementId(newFieldSet.id);

      var tagNames = ['input', 'select', 'textarea'];  // insert other tag names here
      var elements = [];

      for (var i in tagNames) {
        // find all fields for each tag name.
        var fields = newFieldSet.getElementsByTagName(tagNames[i]);
        for(var k = 0; k < fields.length; k++){
          elements.push(fields[k]);
        }
      }

      for (var j in elements) {
        // increment the id for each child element
        elements[j].id = incrementId(elements[j].id);
      }

      document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(newFieldSet);
      window.lastClone = newFieldSet.id;
    }

  </script>


</head>
<body>
<input type='button' value='Clone' onclick='cloneFieldSet()'/><br/>
<fieldset id='fieldset1'>
  <table>

    <tr>
      <td>Label One:</td>
      <td><input type='text' id='fieldOne1'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Label Two:</td>
      <td><input type='text' id='fieldTwo1'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Label Three:</td>
      <td><select id='selectOne1'>
        <option>Some Value</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
<div id='placehere' style='margin:10px 0; border:1px solid black'>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can help with this as well. I have an onchange event that adds the OU# to the Job# field based on the OU selection. 
ie. onchange="document.form.jobid_1.value={$job_id}=this.value

But when the fieldset is cloned, the new section continues to look at jobid_1 instead of jobid_2..

Is there a way I can rewrite the onchange event so that it works for each new section?

Comment: <select id='selectOne1' onchange="updateCounterPart(this)"><option value=''>&nbsp;</option><option value='Some Value'>Some Value</option></select>

function updateCounterPart(select){
    var numberSuffixRegExp = /(.*?)(\d*)$/;
    console.log(select.id);
    var regExpMatch = numberSuffixRegExp.exec(select.id);
    var suffix = regExpMatch[2];
    console.log(suffix);
    var target = document.getElementById('fieldTwo' + suffix);
    if(target){
        target.value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    } else {
        console.log("no target found");
    }    
}

Comment: wow.  that looks awful.  Here's a jsfiddle for the above mess:
[http://jsfiddle.net/perrytew/R2XaC/](http://jsfiddle.net/perrytew/R2XaC/)

Note that I added values to the option fields. I also hardcoded the target text field.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been slowing me down, but now I can finish it up.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This** :   **It only adds an updated id to user input form elements.**

If you want to updated all child elements in the fieldset, remove the **if** statement :)

```
var _counter = 0, _fcounter = 0;

function add(){

    var i, j, 
      oClone = document.getElementById("client1").cloneNode(true),
      fldTypes = "INPUT SELECT TEXTAREA CHECKBOX RADIO",
      fields  = oClone.children;

    _counter++;
    oClone.id += (_counter + "");

    for(i=0, j= fields.length; i<j; i++){
        if(fldTypes.indexOf(fields[i].nodeName) > -1){ //checks for user input form  elements
             _fcounter ++;
           fields[i].id += (_fcounter + "");
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(oClone);

    return oClone;
}
```

**See Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/yfn6u/8/